# Refreshing only a part of a data provider - is this possible?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flex4

Is it possible to refresh only one item in a flex DataProvider?

For example, achieving something like this

```
[Bindable]
private var nodes : VectorCollection = new VectorCollection();

/* thousands of insertions on nodes */

/* Triggered by some event */
public function nodeStatusChanged(nodeId : Number) : void {
      nodes.refresh(nodeId);
}
```

instead of doing `nodes.refresh()` on every `nodeStatusChanged(nodeId)` call.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If you change one element in the collection, it **should** dispatch the appropriate CollectionChange event. I'm making some assumptions here: 1) the VectorCollection class you're using implements the IList interface (so you can use a vector based collection for anything that expects an ArrayCollection or similar IList class), 2) the VectorCollection is dispatching the appropriate CollectionChange event that indicates that one or more items in the collection has changed (like an ArrayCollection does).

Comment: PS: I wrote [my own VectorCollection class](https://github.com/sunild/Flex-Collection-Utils) a few years ago, and it dispatches the proper CollectionChange events. The goal of implementation was to make it as performant as possible by reducing the amount of casting that would occur.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand what your problem is, but if you want only one event to be dispatched by your collection when inserting a lot of values at the same time, then you should use an intermediary vector:

```
var tempVector:Vector.<Node> = new Vector.<Node>();
// Do whatever you need to perform here;
nodes.vector = tempVector;
nodes.refresh();
```

Where you replace Node by the classname you use with your vector. 
In your `refresh()` method, you then dispatch your event:

```
dispatchEvent(new CollectionEvent(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE));
```

Comment: Note you really ought to dispatch a proper collection change event... For example, you are not specifying the type of change (CollectionEventKind). You also are not specifying the items that have changed. For example when the "kind" of the event is CollectionEventKind.ADD, they specify the index of the item that was added, and the item that was added. When it's REPLACE, the pass the index, old item, and the new item. It's not as simple as your example :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this

For update one item in vectorcollection you can use `itemUpdated()` in ICollectionView.

You can use also use the itemUpdated() method to notify the collection of changes to a data provider object if the object does not implement the IEventDispatcher interface;

```
[Bindable]
private var nodes:VectorCollection = new VectorCollection();
```

When you update a field in the nodes VectorCollection, as follows, the control is not automatically updated so use itemUpdated().

```
nodes.getItemAt(0).field1="someOtherValue";

nodes.itemUpdated(nodes.getItemAt(0));

Instead of nodes.refresh();
```